# How to replace values with table map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, replace, dataframe, lookup

I have two dataframes, one with 'encoded' values and another one that acts as a dictionary:

```
> head( encoded_values )
value
1
2
1
3

> head( dict )
id    name
1     foo
2     bar
3     baz
```

I want to *replace* the values in the first data frame with the 'decoded' values by looking up the second data frame. This should be the result:

```
> head( encoded_values )
foo
bar
foo
baz
```

I've found many similar posts but nothing specific to my case. Maybe it's quite a common operation but I'm very new to R and quite lost with all the many possibilities I've tried so far (none of which worked).

Many thanks.

Comment: You want it unordered? As a simple merge can do that `merge(encoded_values, dict, by.x = "value", by.y = "id")`, although will return an ordered result

Comment: Thank you, but `merge` is not the right tool, as it creates a new column rather than replacing the existing one.

Comment: You can delete the old one afterwords.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what `match` (note, much faster than `merge`) is made for:

```
dict[match(encoded_values$value, dict$id), 2, drop=F]
```

produces (we need `drop=F` so that a `data.frame` is returned instead of a vector since we're selecting only one column):

```
    name
1    foo
2    bar
1.1  foo
3    baz
```

`match` returns the location of the values in it's first argument, in the second argument.  You can then use this to index the second argument.

To actually replace:

```
encoded_values$value <- with(dict, name[match(encoded_values$value, id)])
```

**Note**, in this simple case, because your ids match with row numbers in `dict`, you can also do:

```
dict[encoded_values$value, 2, drop=F]
```

but this only works because of the special nature of the `id` variable in `dict` (starts at 1, increments by 1 each).

Comment: Thank you, that did the job and (more important) I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if your `encoded_values` is matrix of **multi-columns**, you can try this as well,

```
words_mapped <- matrix(with(dict, name[match(encoded_values[ ,1:ncol(encoded_values)], id)]), nrow = nrow(encoded_values))
```

this will also work for single column vector in your problem. cheers!